# Alamofire slow response

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for webservice calls. my problem is, app takes time to get the response. Is it because local server? what is wrong with my code?

```
func checkSigninStatus() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let url = URL(string: ServiceUrl.loginStatus)!
        let params: [String: String] = ["emailid": self.emailTxtField.text!, "password": self.passwordTxtField.text!, "mobileno": "0"]
        Alamofire.request(url,method: .post ,parameters : params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default ,headers:headers).responseJSON {response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let data = response.result.value {
                    if  (data as?  Dictionary<String, Any> != nil) {
                        if let dictionaryArray = data as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                            let receivedData = dictionaryArray["data"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
                            if receivedData.count == 0 {
                                self.showAlert(title: "", message:"Invalid Username/Password", view: self)
                            } else {
                                // Tabbar
                                let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MenuStoryboard",
                                                                            bundle: nil)
                                let newViewController1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar")
                                self.present(newViewController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("RESPONSE ERROR: \(error)")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using Alamofire correctly. I'd imagine this is a problem with the server, or your connection.

Comment: @Bharu Am also facing this issue recently. Did you found any solutions on this.